# A function where the area bounded by the tangent line and the two axes is constant.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Okay so I'm trying to find a function or an implicit solution that satisfies this criterion: The area bounded by any tangent to this curve and the two axes must equal a constant $A$, a positive real number.
Of course this area is gonna be a triangle, with height and base equal to the $y$ and $x$ intercepts of the tangent line respectively. I first started by constructing the equation of the tangent line as $a-y=\frac{dy}{dx}(b-x)$ and deriving expressions for the intercepts $a_i$ and $b_i$:
$$
a_i=y-x\frac{dy}{dx} \; ; \; b_i=x-y\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-1}
$$
So then the area would be $\frac 12 a_i b_i=A$. After substituting and a little algebra, I arrived to this differential equation:
$$
x^2(y')^2+2(A-xy)(y')+y^2=0 \; \Rightarrow \; y'=\frac{xy-A\pm\sqrt{A^2-Axy}}{x^2}
$$
Then I used $y=\frac ux$ and $u=v-\frac{v^2}{2A}$ and solved it (the positive root only for now) getting:
$$
v=x+c \; \Rightarrow \; y=1+\frac cx-\frac{(x+c)^2}{2Ax}
$$
So, what do you think about this approach, is it okay? Or have I made an error somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(xy'-y)^2=-2Ay´$, put $y=Bx+C$, and $y'=B$, then $(xB-Bx+C)^2=-2AB \Rightarrow B=C^2/(-2A)$, and then

$$y=C-(C^2x/(2A))$$

Then derive both side by $C$, and comes:  $0=1-(Cx/A) \Rightarrow C= A/x$

and finally $y=A/x-(A^2x/(x^2\cdot2A))= A/x-(A/(2x))=A/(2x)$

Curve is $y= A/(2x)$.

Comment: I've never seen differentiation being used to solve an equation like that before (what you did with C); is that a standard way to do it? Also can you please clarify why my way was wrong? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You must study the theory of " Envelope of a family of curves", so I did. => google.  (If you do the same to your last equation, you will get the same y= A/(2x)...so I can not say, is it wrong at all...)

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry I can't upvote your answer.